# Django admin has no design in live server

Tags: python, django

I uploaded my whole site in my live server after uploading django admin is not showing any design before uploading it was fine but after upload in it got like this :-

[image]

Here is my settings.py I think I did all the thing perfectly but still :( I tried so many time and I got stuck here almost 2 days :) I hope someone will help me with this problem.
Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for gng project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$tl4x!&*01z(0o2r&la&e#)f0dz0x)^bov7dh^aau$m#shktiw'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['gngbd.xyz', 'www.gngbd.xyz']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gng.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gng.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
DEBUG = False

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static'] # Main Line #
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/fonts')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/admicss')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "images/"

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gngxyz/static'),
)
```

Comment: This generally happens if your static file setting is not properly configured, you can read more about how to configure it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: i did everything still same @AkashRanjan

Comment: I think the problem is in your web-server (Nginx?) configuration. It doesn't have a route to your static files. See the requests to CSS/JS files in Chrome devtools and debug why these resources are not served.

Comment: How can i do this ??

Comment: @Sakibovi can you share your settings.py files static file configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to run following command to collect all static files in one place:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

then press `ctrl+F5`. I hope this solves your problem.

And check if you have following in your `settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: i did but still same :( @iliya

Comment: @Sakibovi add your settings as well. Did this work on your local?

Comment: @Sakibovi and one more thing change ```debug``` to ```false``` then check again.

Comment: still same no design

Comment: @Sakibovi add your ```settings.py``` please

Comment: i added settings.py @iliya

Comment: No such file or directory: '/home/pihffall/gngxyz/gng/static' getting this error after adding your lines

Comment: @Sakibovi are you sure you have the folder in the same path you are referring to? And also remove this line ```BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))```, you've defined before.

Comment: is there any way to be sure 100% ??

Comment: can you come to anydesk ??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to collecting your static files, in some web servers you have to reconfigure location of your static files. For example in nginx you have to add the following :

```
location /static {
  autoindex on;
  alias /direction/to/your/static;
}
```